# Reset all actions - interactive filters in Google Data Studio

Tags: looker-studio

Is there any way to force 'reset action' on all interactive filters in a google data studio report without needing to press F5 or refresh the browser page? My users will want the ability to be able to reset actions in a button.

So far I've tried:

- Creating a URL pointing to the report with no parameters, this doesn't refresh the report or reset the filters.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For future reference, the [15 Apr 2021 Update](https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/10331528#apr-15-2021) introduced the respective Reset functionality in Google Data Studio:

> **Reset report filters and selections**
> Report viewers can now use the new Reset report. Reset button to reset all filters and selections they've made. This restores the report to its default view state.

[Editable Google Data Studio Report](https://datastudio.google.com/reporting/7721c37c-74ba-47cd-a0a0-6c27af2a9703) ([Sample Google Analytics](https://datastudio.google.com/datasources/fd360d67-5fbf-4591-8e72-b2e56ea47df8) Data Source) and a GIF to elaborate:

[image]